# Understanding Kernel Ridge Regression from an RKHS point of view

Tags: statistical-inference, machine-learning, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I'd like to verify if my understanding of kernel ridge regression from a mathematical point of view is correct. Especially why this is often described as linear in a high-dimensional space.

#### Step 1: The Representer Theorem

Suppose we are given a dataset $\{(y_{i},x_{i} \}_{i=1}^{n}$ with $y_{i}\in \mathbb{R}$, $x_{i}\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and a kernel function $K:\mathbb{R}^{d}\times\mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ inducing the reproducing kernel hilbert space $\mathcal{H}(K)$.
The Representer Theorem (8.7 Paulsen 2009) tells us that the solution to the minimization problem

$$argmin_{f \in \mathcal{H}(K)} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (y_{i}-f(x_{i}))^{2}+\lambda ||f||_{\mathcal{H}}^{2}$$

is  given by a function $\hat{f} \in span \{ k_{x_{1}}, \ldots, k_{x_{n}} \}$. Therefore $\hat{f}$ can be written as $\hat{f}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}k_{x_{i}}$ where $k_{x_{i}}$  are the reproducing kernels.
Substituting $f$ yields the expression

$$
\begin{aligned}
argmin_{f \in \mathcal{H}(K)} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (y_{i}-f(x_{i}))^{2}+\lambda \left|\left|f\right|\right|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2}
& =
argmin_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left(y_{i}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}k_{x_{j}}(x_{i})\right)^{2}+\lambda \left|\left|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}k_{x_{j}}\right|\right|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2}\\
& =
argmin_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left(y_{i}-(K(x_{i},x_{j}))_{i} \alpha \right)^{2}+\lambda \left|\left|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}k_{x_{j}}\right|\right|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2}\\
& =
argmin_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} \left(y-K\alpha \right)^{T}
\left(y-K\alpha \right)+\lambda\alpha^{T}K\alpha
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore the problem of finding a function in the infinity dimensional function space $\mathcal{H}(K)$ reduced to a minimization problem in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
which has the solution $$\hat{\alpha}=(K+\lambda I)^{-1}y$$.

#### Step 2: Pull-Back Theorem

Let $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ be the pull-back (or feature map) and $K:Y\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a kernel function. From the pull-back theorem (5.7 Paulsen 2009) we can deduce that $K\circ\phi: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is also a Kernel and $\mathcal{H}(K \circ \phi):=\{f\circ \phi : f\in \mathcal{H}(K)\}$

#### Step 3: Kernel Ridge Regression

Let $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ be the feature map and $K_{Y}: Y \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \, K_{Y}(x,y)= \langle x, y \rangle$. Then $\mathcal{H}(K_{Y})$ is the RKHS of bounded linear functionals over $Y$. Using the pull-back theorem, $K_{X}(x,y):= (K_{Y} \circ \phi)(x,y)=\langle \phi(x) ,\phi(y)\rangle $ is a kernel function on $X$. Given a dataset $\{(y_{i},x_{i} \}_{i=1}^{n}$ we want to solve the minimization problem

$$argmin_{f \in \mathcal{H}(K)} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (y_{i}-f(x_{i}))^{2}+\lambda ||f||_{\mathcal{H}}^{2}$$

The solution to this problem was derived under Step 1 and is given by $$\hat{\alpha}=(K+\lambda I)^{-1}y$$ with
$$K=
\left(
 \begin{array}{cccc}
 K_{\mathcal{H}}(\phi(x_{1}),\phi(x_{1})) &  K_{\mathcal{H}}(\phi(x_{1}),\phi(x_{2})) & \ldots & K_{\mathcal{H}}(\phi(x_{1}),\phi(x_{n}))\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 K_{\mathcal{H}}(\phi(x_{n}),\phi(x_{1})) &  K_{\mathcal{H}}(\phi(x_{n}),\phi(x_{1})) & \ldots & K_{\mathcal{H}}(\phi(x_{n}),\phi(x_{n}))\\
\end{array}
 \right)
=
\left(
 \begin{array}{cccc}
 \langle \phi(x_{1}),\phi(x_{1} \rangle &  \langle \phi(x_{1}),\phi(x_{2} \rangle & \ldots &  \langle\phi(x_{1}),\phi(x_{n}\rangle\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\langle \phi(x_{n}) , \phi(x_{1} \rangle &  \langle \phi(x_{n}) , \phi(x_{1} \rangle & \ldots & \langle \phi(x_{n}),\phi(x_{n} \rangle \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

#### Conclusion

$\mathcal{H}(K_{Y})$ is the RKHS of bounded linear functionals and due to the pull-back theorem the function $f\in \mathcal{H}(K_{X})$ is linear in $Y$ which gives rise to the above mentioned interpretation.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of what you've written looks good to me, there is just a terminology issue : you say that "$\mathcal H$ is a RKHS of bounded linear functionals", but that is not correct. Indeed, $\mathcal H$ is a Hilbert Space of **functions**, not functionals, and they need not be linear nor bounded (consider any non-linear kernel : it induces a non-linear function in $\mathcal H(K)$ and you can scale it by any arbitrarily large constant).

What is true however, is that for every point $x$ in the space $X$ over which the functions of $\mathcal H$ are defined, the evaluation functional $T_x:\mathcal H\ni f \mapsto f(x)$ is bounded and linear. That is simply the definition of a RKHS.

Comment: I'm not saying that $\mathcal{H}$ in general is a RKHS of bounded linear functionals, but with the specific choice of $K: Y \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{C},\, K(x,y)= \langle x,y \rangle$ it is.

Comment: Ah indeed with that choice of $K$ and $X=\mathbb R^d$, it can be shown that the elements of $\mathcal{H}(K)$ are linear in the sense that $f(\lambda x + y) = \lambda f(x) + f(y)$ for all $f\in\mathcal{H}(K)$, $x,y\in X$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb K$, so your interpretation is correct. They are not bounded though, and not functionals either.

Comment: This is Proposition 2.24 from [Paulsen](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/an-introduction-to-the-theory-of-reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces/C3FD9DF5F5C21693DD4ED812B531269A). Given an inner product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{L}$ then $K : \mathcal{L} \times \mathcal{L} \rightarrow \mathbb{C},\; K(x,y)=\langle x, y \rangle$ is a kernel function on $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{H}(K)$ is the vector space of bounded linear functionals on $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: I see, when $X=\mathcal L$ is a general Hilbert space, then [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) tells you that all the maps $\phi :x\in X\mapsto \langle x,x_\phi\rangle$ define all bounded linear functionals $\phi$ on $X$, hence $\mathcal{H}(K)$ is a space of bounded linear functionals. In the case $X=\mathbb R^d$, although it is very much a Hilbert space, so the $\mathcal{H}(K)$ can be thought of as bounded linear functionals, it is more common to simply refer to them as "functions" or "linear forms". So yeah, just a terminology issue.